# How to add active class on scroll in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Here's a demo in Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/Du5J120AIkNqnnpR30le?p=preview)**

I have a few `div` elements with `data-msid` ('1', '2', '3'), and each one has a corresponding `li` in **footer** with `data-msidatrr` ('1', '2', '3').

**PROBLEM:**

I want to add active class on `footer li` when the user scrolls and the corresponding `div` becomes visible in `viewport`.

**EXAMPLE:**

When `id='first' data-msid="1"` appears in the viewport, `li data-msidatrr="1"` in footer should have an `active` class, and so on for the rest of the `div` and `footer li`.

**Here's my jQuery code:**

```
$(function(){
    $.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
        var win = $(window);

        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft()
        };

        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

        var bounds = this.offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.outerHeight();

        return ( ! (
            viewport.right < bounds.left ||
            viewport.left > bounds.right ||
            viewport.bottom < bounds.top ||
            viewport.top > bounds.bottom
        ));
    }; /* END $.fn.isOnScreen */

    $( "#container" ).scroll(function() {
        console.log('scrlling');

        $.each( $('#container>div'), function(i, left) {
            console.log(i);
            var msid = $(left).attr('data-msid');
            console.log($(left).attr('data-msid'));
            console.log($('#first').isOnScreen());
            $('.fC[data-msidatrr=]+msid').addClass('active');
        })
    });
}) /* END $(function() */
```

Comment: Isn't better to use a plugin like SrollSpy, Waypoints, or Skrollr? It seems like you're trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: i don't want to use any plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**## Here's a working JSFiddle.**

**First, you have some errors in your HTML and jQuery:**

```
<!-- wrong div id -->
<div id='second' data-msid="12">
<!-- correct div id -->
<div id='second' data-msid="2">

<!-- wrong -->
<li class='item data-msidatrr="3"'>third</li>
<!-- correct -->
<li class='item' data-msidatrr="3">third</li>
```

---

```
// wrong
$('.fC[data-msidatrr=]+msid').addClass('active');
// correct
$(".fC li[data-msidatrr='" + msid + "']").addClass('active');
```

---

**Second, consider using this neat function to detect if a div is visible in your `#container` on scroll:
*[(credits to reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/2562819)***

```
function isScrolledToView(el) {
    var container = document.getElementById('container').getBoundingClientRect();
    var div = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log('container.top = '+container.top+'; container.bottom = '+container.bottom)

    return ((div.top >= container.top) && (div.top <= container.bottom));
}
```

The code above will simplify your code, since you won't be needing `$.fn.isOnScreen` anymore.

---

**BONUS (optional):**

- enclose your HTML element attributes with double quotes, not single quotes:

  - `id="container"` NOT `id='container'`
- in the case of your `third` and `fourth` div, they will be "active" at the same time because of their short height, so you might want to do something with it.